# import selenium to python

Tags: python, django, selenium

I installed selenium to my mac using pip. and when I tried to run this the file that has this code in the terminal:

```
from selenium import webdrive
browser = webdrive.Firefox
browser.get("http://localhost:8000")
assert "Django" in browser.title
```

it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_test.py", line 1, in <module>
  from selenium import webdrive
  ImportError: cannot import name webdrive
```

I think python is not importing selenium...
any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `webdriver`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: I figured it out... the text editor was stuck and of course it should be webdriver not webdrive ... thank you very much